# Podman container on rhel8 giving "error retrieving network namespace ..." error

Tags: podman, rhel8

When I run podman commands on my rhel8 machine, e.g. `podman ps`, I've started receiving the following error:

> ERRO[0000] error joining network namespace for container <containerId>: error retrieving network namespace at : unknown FS magic on "<container location>"

It was working fine earlier in the week. any pointers?

Comment: I can get around it by stopping and launching the container forcefully, but this is a repeat issue, and I don't think stopping and re-launching is a good solution. This is how I stop: podman rm --force <containerId>

Answer (score 1):

Ok for me after stopping the process...

```
~$ podman container stop <containerId>
```

No more error on container list

```
~$ podman container ls
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                           COMMAND     CREATED         STATUS             PORTS       NAMES
2621211781e1  docker.io/library/mysql:8.0.27  mysqld      31 minutes ago  Up 31 minutes ago              some-mysql
```